# using `draw_filled_circle_mut` in a function: trait bound not satisfied

Tags: rust

Using `imageproc` crate, I can call `draw_filled_circle_mut` on an Image:

```
let mut img = ImageBuffer::from_pixel(640, 480, Rgb([255, 0, 0]));
draw_filled_circle_mut(&mut img, (300, 300), 50, Rgb([0, 255, 0]));
```

But if I use a function it does not work:

```
fn circle(img: &mut RgbImage) {
    draw_filled_circle_mut(&mut img, (300, 300), 50, Rgb([0, 255, 0]));
}

fn main() {
    let mut img = ImageBuffer::from_pixel(640, 480, Rgb([255, 0, 0]));
    circle(&mut img);
}
```

It returns this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>: image::GenericImage` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:84:5
   |
84 |     draw_filled_circle_mut(&mut img, (300, 300), 50, Rgb([10,255,10]));
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `image::GenericImage` is not implemented for `&mut image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
         <image::ImageBuffer<P, Container> as image::GenericImage>
   = note: required by `imageproc::drawing::draw_filled_circle_mut`
```

I'm still lost with this kind of error. I thought I can draw on a `RgbImage` which is a `ImageBuffer<Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>` and that's what IS my `img` var (unless I did not understand).

So why does it work in the same function (without actually writing type) and it does not work when I use another function (with a typed argument)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fn circle(img: &mut RgbImage) {
    draw_filled_circle_mut(&mut img, ...
```

Type of `img` is `&mut RgbImage` and then you take another mutable reference of it. That is you try to pass `&mut &mut RgbImage` into `draw_filled_circle_mut`, while it expects `&mut RgbImage`.

Correct version

```
fn circle(img: &mut RgbImage) {
    draw_filled_circle_mut(img, (300, 300), 50, Rgb([0, 255, 0]));
}
```

What about error message? Let's look at the declaration of the function

```
pub fn draw_filled_circle_mut<I>(
    image: &mut I, 
    center: (i32, i32), 
    radius: i32, 
    color: I::Pixel
) 
where
    I: GenericImage,
    I::Pixel: 'static,
```

The function expects `&mut I` as a first parameter and type `I` must implement trait `GenericImage`. You pass `&mut &mut RgbImage` into the function, which means that `I` is `&mut RgbImage`.

Compiler checks whether `&mut RgbImage` implements `GenericImage` trait, finds that it is not, and outputs error message telling that.